# ELK stack in AWS to search application data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

input file: csv

eg: ~DEALER_ID~,~STOCK_ID~,~VIN~,~IS_NEW~,~IS_CERTIFIED~,~YEAR~,~MAKE~,~MODEL~

~1035659~,~C0524359~,~2LMDJ6J45454359~,~N~,~N~,~2013~,~Lincoln~,~MKX~

~1035659~,~C0532359~,~345666543344443~,~N~,~N~,~2016~,~BMW~,~X5~

...

...

Location: S3

As soon as the csv is dropped in S3, I would like the data to be ingested into AWS managed ElasticSearch. Im very new to ELK stack and AWS elastic search, so I'd like some suggestions on best way to get this working on AWS.

I was able to parse this file by running logstash locally and sending it to my local ElasticSearch and Kibana servers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to run a Lambda function and add a trigger such that when a new file arrives in S3 your function is triggered and Lambda ingests the data into AWS ES

Comment: Do you suggest converting the file format above into json and ingesting into ES. Is there a good tutorial I could use for ingesting application data?

Comment: Hi, converting into json may not be required, code your Lambda function to parse csv data into individual fields so you are you able to aggregate and visualize on your data. I am not sure if AWS managed ES supports ingest node, if it does you can create ingest pipelines to parse your data during indexing and just use Lambda to simply index data.

Comment: Some tutorials for ingesting data https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/indexing-metadata-in-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda-and-python/